# CSS/JS Get the width of a glyph

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, glyph

I'm using a font as a way to display vector images, and it has very wide glyphs. They happen to be so large they get out of the div they are in:

[image]

The blue gun is a rotating glyph contained in a div. When I try to get its size, it doesn't give me the full length of the glyph.

Because of that, I can't center it.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Please don't forget to include the font where this glyph comes from in your [MCVE]. (If you could produce a new font with only this glyph, but which still reproduces the error that would be great).

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the CSS would definitely help. Without seeing that, my best thought would be setting max width as a percent to scale.

```
    .your-selector.class{
        max-width: 50%;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, that didn't seemd relevent to me. Setting the max-width to 50% worked so thank you !